# Location of the roots of the equation $f(x)+2f'(x)+f''(x)=0$ if $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ are the roots of $f(x)=0$

Tags: roots, cubics

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> If the cubic equation $f(x)=0$ has three real roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ such that $\alpha\lt\beta\lt\gamma$, show that the equation $$f(x)+2f'(x)+f''(x)=0$$ has a real root between $\alpha$ and $\gamma$.

---

**Attempt at a solution:-**

If $f(x)$ is a quadratic equation whose roots are $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$, then 
$$f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)$$
From this we get $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ as follows:-
$$f'(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)+(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)+(x-\gamma)(x-\alpha)\\
=3x^2-2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)x+(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)$$
$$f''(x)=2(3x-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma))$$

$$\therefore f(x)+2f'(x)+f''(x)=x^3-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma-6)x^2+(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha-4(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)+6)x+(\alpha\beta\gamma+2(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)-2(\alpha+\beta+\gamma))$$

Now, after seeing this humongous expression for $f(x)+2f'(x)+f''(x)$ and not able to find anything useful that could have shortened the solution, I thought that it would be fun to play around with the expression by putting $x=\alpha$ and $x=\gamma$ and then proving that both have opposite signs but it turned out to be totally opposite of fun, it just made me break down after spending a lot of time.

> Your help is very essential to solve this problem. Maybe you can just give me a thought on how to approach the question in a not so disgusting manner as I did.

Comment: @NickLiu - If you want you can take $f(x)$ to be that but I aint gonna fall for that again, for me the three roots were hard enough to handle during the last stage of my attempt hence I posted one with the leading coefficient as unity. But, if you have an idea where I do not have to gp through a lot of pain to come up till the solution then please do tell me.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a nice trick: Let $g(x)=f(x)e^x$. Then $g'(x)=(f'(x)+f(x))e^x$ and $g''(x)=(f''(x)+2f'(x)+f(x))e^x$. By what is given, $g$ has three roots $\alpha<\beta<\gamma$. By Rolle, $g'$ has a root strictly between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as well as one strictly between $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Hence by Rolle again, $g''$ has a root between these two roots of $g'$. As $e^x\ne 0$, this root of $g''$ is also a root of $f+2f'+f''$.

*Remark:* We did not use the fact that $f$ is cubic. It suffices that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: (+1)That was a super-trick. Can you tell me the inspiration behind your solution.